# Passing byte[] array to another view

Tags: java, android

I have been at this for hours now and I just have no idea on how to pass a byte[] array to another view when I call `OnItemClick`. I have tried converting the byte array to a string and back but that doesn't work. I can't do `get(position)` like I could on a normal string array.

Sorry if this is basic but I honestly have no clue on how to due this.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    if (view.equals(footerView)) {
        footerView.showProgress();
        List<Status> olderTimeline = loadOlderTweets();
        insertTimeline(olderTimeline);
        attachAdapter();
    } else {
        // i want to do something like this on the byte[] array
        result_pos = timeline_arg.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), TDetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("username", result_pos.get("username"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variable is byte array?Do you want to send byte array to TDetailActivity?

Comment: @GiruBhai Yes I want to send a byte array to TDetailActivity, the byte array is declared in onCreateView

Comment: Which variable is byte array?Please post more code.

Comment: I think we have an answer for your question already here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
extras.putByteArray(key, value);
```

Then, in the launched Activity, you would read them via:

```
byte[] value = getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your byte array as

```
Intent in1 = new Intent(this, TDetailActivity.class);
in1.putExtra("image",byteArray);
```

And in `TDetailActivity` retrieve byte array as

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
```

Change **image** with the key of your byte array.